# Drawing an arc between 2 nodes with a specific radius

Tags: tikz-pgf

I use the following code, as a part of a complicated drawing, to draw an arc specifying start angle, end angle, radius.

Is it possible to draw the same arc from node z to node x with radius .5cm (i.e. maintaining the shape of the arc without enlarging it). I tried to fake the end of the arc at node x by making the radius .88cm (as shown in the lower figure); but I need to maintain the radius .5cm.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\node [thin, black] (0,0) (oscnd){}
 ([shift={(180.:.3)}]oscnd.center) node (oscndl){}
 ([shift={(90.:.3)}]oscndl.center) node (oscndlu){} node{\textcolor{red} x}
 ([shift={(180.:1.)}]oscndlu.center) node (oscndlul){}
 ([shift={(-90.:.3)}]oscndl.center) node (oscndld){} node{\textcolor{red}z}
 ([shift={(180.:1.)}]oscndld.center) node (oscndldl){}
;
 \draw[thick,  green, fill=green!40!white, opacity=.4] (oscndldl.center) -- (oscndld.center) arc (-160:160:.5cm) -- (oscndlu.center) -- (oscndlul.center);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

This drawing is a part of the following figure. It was made with a circle not an arc.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Edit:** At the request of OP, addition of some mathematical elements

According to my calculs and if I understood your question correctly, this arc of circle starts at an angle of `180+asin(3/5)` and ends at `180-asin(3/5)`.

[image: arc-cercle]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\node [thin, black] (0,0) (oscnd){}
 ([shift={(180.:.3)}]oscnd.center) node (oscndl){}
 ([shift={(90.:.3)}]oscndl.center) node (oscndlu){} node{\textcolor{red} x}
 ([shift={(180.:1.)}]oscndlu.center) node (oscndlul){}
 ([shift={(-90.:.3)}]oscndl.center) node (oscndld){} node{\textcolor{red}z}
 ([shift={(180.:1.)}]oscndld.center) node (oscndldl){}
;
 \draw[thick,  green, fill=green!40!white, opacity=.4] (oscndldl.center) -- (oscndld.center) arc (-180+asin(3/5):180-asin(3/5):.5cm) -- (oscndlu.center) -- (oscndlul.center);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

### Some elements of geometry:

In a rectangular triangle with a hypotenuse of length 1 unit, the sinus of an acute angle is the length of the opposite side. Here the sinus of the angle AOB (alpha) is the length of the side AB.

[image: triangle-rectangle]

A circle with a radius of 1 unit is called a trigonometric circle. 
The circle below has a radius of 1 unit. The sine of 140° is equal to the sine of 40°. since the segments colored blue have the same length.

[image: cercle-trigo]

For each angle between 90° and 180° corresponds a single length, a single sinus. Thus, requiring that a length be equal to the sinus is equivalent to imposing an alpha angle measurement.
[image: sinus]

On your figure, the sinus is equal to 0.3  `[shift={(90.:.3)}]` and the hypotenuse is equal to 0.5 `arc (-160:160:.5cm)`.

[image: your-figure]

Which imposes an angle such as I calculated it. If you want to change this angle, you must either change the sine : `[shift={(90.:.3)}]` or change the hypotenuse, i. e. the radius of the circle arc `(-160:160:.5cm)`

### Some additional explanation on the solution (at the request of the OP):

Since the radius of the trigonometric circle is equal to 1 unit, then the sine is smaller than 1. 
The sinus functions `sin()` and arcsine `asin()` are called **reciprocal**.

The `sine` function, as its name suggests, when the angle is between 0° and 90°, gives the **length** of the opposite side `AB` of the angle `AOB` in the triangle AOB, for example `sin(20)=0,342...`

The `arcsine` function does "the opposite", i. e. from a given length (smaller than 1 unit) gives the corresponding angle.

Since `0.5` is the hypotenuse (radius of the circle) is **half** of 1 unit, the corresponding sinus is **twice** as much as 0.3, i.e. 0.6.

This sinus is found directly by dividing 0.3/0.5=0.6 (which is equivalent to 3/5=0.6).
Thus the formula calculates the angle whose **sinus** is equal to 0.3 and the **hypotenuse** is equal to 0.5

This angle (you can calculate it with the calculator installed on your computer) is around 36.87...° `asin(3/5)=36,869897645844021296855612559093...°`

I add this angle at 180 to get the starting angle of the arc to be drawn and I remove it at 180° to get its terminal angle.
I could very well have (and I am correcting my solution) written `arc (-180+asin(3/5):180-asin(3/5):.5cm)`.

Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator

Comment: Thank you very much. Just one more request please. Can the starting angle be -170 instead of -160, and the end angle be 170 instead of 160; so the arc would look more curved.

Comment: @Hany I did not understand your request correctly. In the solution I gave `180-asin(3/5) =143,13°...` and `180+asin(3/5)=-143,13°...` What do you mean with 160° or 170°?

Comment: My original code was drawing an arc with the specifications (-160:160:.5cm), I would like it to be (-170:170:.5cm). I will appreciate it, if you have the time to explain to me what your code means, and how can I modify it.

Comment: @Hany If you change the angles, the radius of the circle will no longer be the same. Do you want a solution with 170°, but with a different radius?

Comment: No, I want it with 170 degree and with radius .5cm, if possible.

Comment: @Hany Then you must modify the translations of 0.3. `[shift={(90.:.3)}]`. Do you want to change this setting?

Comment: No, keep [shift={(90.:.3)}]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83798/discussion-between-andrec-and-hany).

Comment: @Hany You are welcome :)

Answer (score 6):

Just for fun and learning... an implementation to create the shapes depending on the values of line width, line longitude, circle termination radio, condition `line_width<=termination_radio`; extended to the red shape in two drawing definitions. `decorations.fractals` is used for the right termination in the red shape.

RESULT:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.fractals}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[]

    \def\GreenShape(#1)[#2][#3][#4]
    {%1: Position 2: Line width 3:Line Longitude 4: Circle termination radio 
        \pgfmathparse{asin(0.5*#2/#4)}
        \edef\Theta{\pgfmathresult}
        \draw[
            fill=green!50!black,
            preaction={%For the shadow
                transform canvas={shift={(2pt,-3pt)}},
                fill=gray,
                fill opacity=0.4,
            }
        ](#1) |- ++(#3,0.5*#2) arc (180-\Theta:\Theta-180:#4) -| cycle;
        \path(#1)-- ++(#3,0.5*#2)++(-\Theta:#4) coordinate (A);
        \shade[inner color=yellow, outer color=green!50!black](A) circle (0.8*#4);
        \shade[inner color=yellow, outer color=green!50!black](A) circle (0.5*#4);
    }

    %For the red shape:
    \def\RedShape(#1)[#2][#3][#4]
    {%1: Position 2: Line width 3:Line Longitude 4: Circle termination size
        \draw[
            decoration=Koch snowflake,
            fill=red,
            thick,
            preaction={%For the shadow
                transform canvas={shift={(2pt,-3pt)}},
                fill=gray,
                fill opacity=0.4,
            }
        ]
        (#1)++(#4,-0.5*#2) coordinate (init)
            .. controls +(-180:0.5) and +(-45:0.1) .. ++(-#4*1.5,-0.5*#2) 
            .. controls +(135:0.1) and +(-90:0.2) .. ++(#4*0.5,#2)
            .. controls +(90:0.2) and +(-135:0.1) .. ++(-#4*0.5,#2)
            .. controls +(45:0.1) and +(-180:0.5) .. ++(#4*1.5,-0.5*#2)
            -- ++(0.4*#3,0)         
            .. controls +(90:0.5) and +(-90:0.5) .. ++(-#4+0.25*#2,#4+0.7) coordinate (ball)
            arc (180:0:#4)
            .. controls +(-90:0.5) and +(90:0.5) .. ++(-#4+0.25*#2,-#4-0.7)
            -- ++(0.6*#3,0)
            decorate{decorate{--++(#4*1.5,0.5*#2) -- ++(0,-#2*2) --++(-#4*1.5,+0.5*#2)}}
            -- (init)           
        ;
        \path (ball)++(#4,0) coordinate (B);
        \shade[inner color=yellow, outer color=red!70!black](B) circle (0.5*#4);        
    }

    %Start drawing the thing
    \GreenShape(0,0)[0.5][1][0.5]
    \RedShape(2.1,0)[0.5][6][0.5]   
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it is very inspiring.